# Has Nursing Always Been Female Dominated Like Today (90+%)?

Tags: united-states, medicine, women

I had a discussion with a nursing friend (male nurse) and he said that he wouldn't be a nurse if he had the chance again due to often being asked to do things no other nurse wants (like getting the undesirable patients, doing the dirtier/nastier work, etc).  He made an observation that I can't find any data on - in the past, men may have been more likely to be nurses because *all jobs sucked in the past*, such as dangerous farming or mining (much more dangerous than today).  Relatively speaking, his point was nursing wasn't *as bad comparatively* in those times, thus more men would have been likely to do it.

In the United States, 92% of nurses are female, but I can't seem to find any data about male nursing 100 years ago, or even 50 years ago, even though nursing has been around a while.  Is there any historic data of gender and nursing from 50-100 years ago as a comparative point?

Comment: Modern medicine in any meaningful sense of the term originates in the confluence of the innovations pioneered by [Florence Nightingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Nightingale), [Sir William Osler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Osler), and [Dominique Jean Larrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Jean_Larrey). I suggest you begin your research there.

Comment: The term 'nurse' comes from the occupation 'wet-nurse', and I'd be very surprised if that wasn't female dominated...

Comment: Also, a quick look at Wikipedia's [history of nursing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_nursing#Modern) would show that nursing has pretty much *always* been a mostly female profession, due to nurses often being nuns, wet-nurses, and midwives.

Comment: Until later in the 20th C, a male nurse would most probably indicate an attendant where people had to be physically restrained, such as institutes for the insane. Whether they would have any actual *nursing* skill or training I doubt.

Comment: I'm in the UK but have experience of US nursing. They told me it was very underpaid, and from my own observation very undervalued also. Is it also possible that low paid work drew women as it often does, and men couldnt take it as a first job because it didnt pay enough?

Comment: @bigbadmouse The US has a very bureaucratic medical system. We spend more of our time in compliance, legalities, and paper work than helping patients.  In addition, we all have to have insurance to protect us from lawsuits (yes, happens to nurses too) and these costs suck.  Bureaucratic professions are just awful in general - very little time is spent helping.

Comment: @MsJackson we were shocked at how badly nurses were treated in the US (orlando in our case). Nurses are by and large hugely respected here in the UK. I don't think the at-point-of-care funding system helps. That's a whole layer that patient and practitioner can overlook here.

Comment: Medieval equivalents of nurses can be nuns and monks from monasteries. Actually there were several orders that were very active on healthcare. Also, many surgical and war related medical practices was done by barbers and similar folks, so depending what you call a nurse, you can find heavily male dominated institutions, too

Comment: @Greg Fascinating thought - didn't think about that.  It does seem like some private institutions like religious did care for people.  Not officially nursing, but the work was intended to produce the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern nursing came to being [during the Crimean war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Nightingale), and was a 100% female thing for all practical intents at the time.

US census might have data on job occupation by sex - I haven't checked - as might its UK, French, and German equivalents. But intuitively your friend is incorrect: until a few decades ago, doctors were nearly always men and nurses were nearly always women.

Comment: With so many wars during the life of nursing, I agree that up to this point the profession would probably be much more female and I doubt we've ever seen many males nurses.  It will be interesting to see the nursing breakdown if we ever enter a long period of peace and if males enter the profession at a higher rate.

Comment: @MsJackson: Indeed. I hope to see that in my lifetime, in point of fact. But I'm not optimistic considering the way the US, of all places, seems to be quickly becoming the world's most dangerous threat to peace since WW1.